# Merging only records in a Group

Tags: duplicate-contacts

i wanted to just merge records that are in a Group.  But the documentation seems to indicate that the records that will be flagged as duplicates will be from where at least 1 of the record is within the Group.  How can i configure to flag pairs where both records are from the designated Group?  Thanks.

CiviCRM: 5.10.4
WordPress Version: 5.0.9

Comment: don't think this is currently possible but agree it is a reasonable process to want to take

Answer (score 2):

A way to achieve this would be to create an ACL that limits records to that group and then assign that ACL to a user and they will only see those records to dedupe.

Answer (score 1):

If @Andy Burns answer does not work for any reason I would try putting all duplicate candidates in a new (smart) group and then search contacts that has to be in *both* groups: the original and the new – ordered by name or display name.